# How to use MS Project to plan Bachelor degree modules

Tags: ms-project, personal-skills, small-projects

In an attempt to keep abreast of all prerequisites for my bachelor degree, as well as the grades and GPA, I have decided to put all the data in an MS Project file.

There are certain modules which consist of 3 practical elements, each must be passed in order to be granted entrance to the exam. Some practicals also count toward the final grade.

Certain modules serve as prerequisites for others.

I would also like to break up each module into individual study sessions by topic i.e. Physics 101: 1D, 2D, Electrical Circuit etc.

Also: I am not studying linearly as most do, but as I am working, I try to fit the modules around my work schedule and am having trouble keeping on top of things.

Is MS Project a realistic method for this?

Right now I have organised into the following hierarchies:

- Basic
- Main
- Thesis

With each divided into their relevant semesters

Basic
-Semester 1
-Semester 2

Main
-Semester 3
-Semester 4 etc.

Semester 2
 - Mathematics 2
 - - practical
 - - - exam

Etc.. along with an overview of the topics to be learned for every subject.

Some of these don't have deadlines, they just need to be done, whereas others, such as homework and practicals, have deadlines.

How do I reconcile all this?

Comment: To be honest, I would probably not recommend Project for this process.  Firstly, Project does have a fairly steep learning curve (to use it well and have it work for you versus against you.)  I don't imagine that learning Project in order to keep yourself on track doesn't add to your already full plate.  I'd try to come up with a study schedule and perhaps use Outlook (ability to add reminders), Excel (keeping track of grades), and possibly OneNote.

Comment: The sad thing is: project management is one of the modules. ..so my thinking wad that this is a two birds,  one stone kind of deal

Comment: I understand but is MS Project one of the modules?  Different processes - while you should know PM principles to use MS Project - it doesn't necessarily follow that you have to use MS Project.

Comment: Hey JulieS thanks for the perspective and apologies for not getting back to you. I guess I could just take a course when it comes up in my career. Most news I've had is that MS Project isn't necessarily ideal anyhow.

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of 'ideal' is - but it has worked fine for millions and for me for the last 20+ years.

Answer (score 2):

MS Project (or similar tools) is good for to schedule management related PM activities,e.g.:

- highlight and visualise relationships (prerequisites etc.)
- track delays and identify the consequences

Having (at least) those two capabilities it might help you to track and prioritise your activities.

I can't imagine what to do with grades within MS Project beside just noting them. If you would like to do some statistical work with your grades, you should consider a tool like MS Excel.